# SQL to Filter timestamp using the where clause on day or time

Tags: php, sql, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I am having this table and i am trying to filter records based on day or based on month from the **date_time_stamp** field

```
+---------------+-----------------+
| name          | date_time_stamp |
+---------------+-----------------+
| John          |      1329828975 |
+---------------+-----------------+
| Ken           |      1428728929 |
+---------------+-----------------+
| Bennedict     |      1526758965 |
+---------------+-----------------+
| Lily          |      1725498952 |
+---------------+-----------------+
```

The following SQL was only able to get the day, month and year from the table but adding a **WHERE day=5** flags error

```
SELECT us.lessons_ID,
us.from_timestamp,
us.users_LOGIN,
       DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(us.from_timestamp)) as 'day',
       MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(us.from_timestamp))  as 'month',
        YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(us.from_timestamp))  as 'year'
   FROM users_to_lessons  us
```

so my question is how do i filter records from this table were month equal **May or June e.t.c** or filter based on **day** or even filter based on **Month, Day and Year**

Would be glad if someone can give me a clue

Comment: `WHERE DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(us.from_timestamp)) = 5`

Comment: To add to @GiorgosBetsos comment: you cannot use aliases in a `WHERE` clause, you have to use the full statement. Unless you want to do some subquery magic.

Comment: Please tag your dbms (as the sql tag asked you to).

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Thanks a bunch, ur solution worked like a charm.. Just going thru ur blog now http://giorgosbetsos.blogspot.com.ng/ and i will say its a handfull of DBMS/SQL solutions..

i would really love to have u on my contact list
SKYPE, WATSAPP, FB, TWITTER, on which can i connect with you ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @GiorgosBetsos.

The right SQL becomes this

```
SELECT us.lessons_ID,
us.from_timestamp,
us.users_LOGIN,
       DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(us.from_timestamp)) as 'day',
       MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(us.from_timestamp))  as 'month',
        YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(us.from_timestamp))  as 'year'
   FROM users_to_lessons  us

   WHERE DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(us.from_timestamp)) = 5
```